# Android FragmentPagerAdapter with LoaderManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-loadermanager

I have a FragmentActivity with a ViewPager and a FragmentPagerAdapter.

Each fragment in the ViewPager needs to load data from a webservice.  I've written the LoaderManager/custom Loaders to perform the webservice calls, parse the XML etc and these are working fine.

There are two possible designs for managing the loading and fragments.

1) The main activity to manages the loading on behalf of the fragments.

The fragment makes a call back to the main FragmentActivity requesting it's data.  The activity checks if a loader for that data is already running, if not it creates one and performs the load.

In this case how do I tell the fragment that the data has been loaded and is ready for painting. I am using custom loaders not simplecursors so the fragment will populate its textviews etc from an object instance so it must be told when the objects have been populated.

It doesn't seem that a FragmentPagerAdapter allows you to allocate Tags or Id's to the fragments when you instantiate them in getItem.  How can I find the fragment from the FragmentActivity and tell it to paint its data?

2) Each fragment manages its own loading.

The fragment initialises its own Loader, each fragment has its own onCreateLoader/onLoaderFinish etc.

The problem I've come across here is if the user pages off that page whilst the loader is running the fragment seems to be destroyed (sometimes).  As a result the onLoaderFinished isn't being called and the fragment can't tell the main activity that it's finished - the main activity is controlling a progress indicator (setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility) in an actionbar.

So what is the best design pattern when you have a FragmentPagerAdapter, a ViewPager with several pages which need their own loaders?

Another issue I've encountered is using getSupportLoaderManager to check if any loaders are running.  I call this from the onLoadFinished.  If no loaders running I can hide the progress indicator.  However the hasRunningLoaders sometimes returns true, even though all the loaders have completed.

```
        LoaderManager lm = getSupportLoaderManager();

    // If the loader is not already running, start it...
    if (! lm.hasRunningLoaders()) {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
```

Many thanks for any advice or pointing me in the direction of some decent samples.

Ta
Martin.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to design 1, I did something like this by maintaining a reference variable to the fragments that I create.  In your FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem method, you can assign the created fragment to that variable before returning it.  This will allow access to your fragments from the main activity.

Comment: Thanks, I assume that if the FragmentPagerAdapter frees a fragment when user pages to another you would have to remove the reference by overriding destroyItem. Then re-add a new reference to the newly created fragment when getItem is called again.

Shame FragmentPagerAdapter doesn't support finding the fragments it's managing.

I'm in two minds whether it's better for each fragment to be fairly dumb and just know how to display the data it's given, or whether it's better for each fragment to know how to load its own data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is entirely correct, but I remember that when your Fragment is destroyed while a Loader is getting data in the background, the `onLoaderReset` method is called (instead of the `onLoaderFinished`). This would allow you to reset your progress indicator appropriately.